# async Task timing out

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am writing a page in Xamarin that displays a YouTube search using the YouTube Data API. It compiles fine but when I run it on my Android device it freezes and after awhile prompts to quit the application because it's not responding. I think it has something to do with establsihing the YouTubeService object.

This basically calls the data API and loads 50 of the videos for the given search term into the listview

```
private async Task Run()
    {
        videoList.Clear();

        var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = DEVELOPER_KEY,
            ApplicationName = "Xamarin-Basics"
        });

        var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
        searchListRequest.Q = "mkbhd";
        searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

        var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

        foreach(var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
        {
            if (searchResult.Id.Kind.Equals("youtube#video"))
            {
                videoList.Add(new VideoInfo(searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Snippet.Description));
            }
        }
    }
```

Also, here is the stack trace which appears to be running the operation in the thread over and over again:

```
09-15 20:31:21.352 D/Mono    ( 6831): Assembly Ref addref     Newtonsoft.Json[0xb72c8210] -> System.Linq.Expressions[0xb72e98a0]: 3
Loaded assembly: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly [External]
09-15 20:31:21.562 D/Mono    ( 6831): Assembly Ref addref     Google.Apis.YouTube.v3[0xb72c7310] -> Newtonsoft.Json[0xb72c8210]: 4
09-15 20:31:22.127 D/Mono    ( 6831): DllImport searching in: '__Internal'     ('(null)').
09-15 20:31:22.127 D/Mono    ( 6831): Searching for 'CloseZStream'.
09-15 20:31:22.127 D/Mono    ( 6831): Probing 'CloseZStream'.
09-15 20:31:22.127 D/Mono    ( 6831): Found as 'CloseZStream'.
09-15 20:31:31.950 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb76fa5b0] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #3
The thread 'Unknown' (0x3) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-15 20:31:57.148 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb808e9b8] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #7
The thread 'Unknown' (0x7) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-15 20:32:04.446 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb77219d8] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #4
The thread 'Unknown' (0x4) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #2
The thread 'Unknown' (0x2) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-15 20:32:49.051 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb808de40] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #8
The thread 'Unknown' (0x8) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #11
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #12
09-15 20:32:59.725 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb81d8738] worker starting
09-15 20:33:30.573 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb81d8738] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #12
The thread 'Unknown' (0xc) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
09-15 20:33:46.394 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb80a4790] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #9
The thread 'Unknown' (0x9) has exited with code 0 (0x0). 
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #11
The thread 'Unknown' (0xb) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #13
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #14
09-15 20:34:39.731 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb81d8738] worker starting
Thread started: <Thread Pool> #15
09-15 20:34:39.749 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb84d0f60] worker starting
09-15 20:34:52.494 D/Mono    ( 6831): [0xb84d0f60] worker finishing
Thread finished: <Thread Pool> #15
The thread 'Unknown' (0xf) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: which version of the youtube dll do you have?

Comment: Version 3 is what I have

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks basically right. I am assuming you are using the latest `v3` api:

```
Google.Apis.YouTube.v3" version="1.16.0.582"
```

I would try wrapping the whole routine in a try/catch just to make sure that you are not getting a 403 or other access/auth error:

`Xamarin.Android` example:

```
try
{
    var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        ApiKey = DEVELOPER_KEY,
        ApplicationName = "com.sushihangover.youtubeapi",
    });
    var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
    searchListRequest.Q = "StackOverflow";
    searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;

    var searchListResponse = await searchListRequest.ExecuteAsync();

    foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
    {
        if (searchResult.Id.Kind.Equals("youtube#video"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(searchResult.Snippet.Title);
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't catch anything. Left it running and it's been looping, I posted the stack trace above.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on `var searchListRequest...` does it ever get there? How are you calling your `Run` method?

Comment: It gets there but never gets past there; the foreach loop isn't ever reached. I have another method that is an event handler for a button click and inside is Run().Wait();

Comment: @EthanWilliams Basic questions:  You have internet access from that Android device? Can you surf to youtube.com in the browser? Assuming you have the Youtube API enabled in google's dev console, are providing a valid DEVELOPER_KEY, ...

Comment: Yep all of that is good. I just tried making it run in the main thread and it works exactly as I wanted it to. Any idea why it had trouble running asynchonorously?

Comment: What happens if you run `ExecuteAsync()` with `.ConfigureAwait(false)`? Also if you are doing `Run().Wait()` you are really defeating the purpose of async.

Comment: It gives me an error in searchListResponse.Items because the iems may not be retirved before the loop starts. Run().Wait() was the recommended method in the API overview, though when I took this off async worked perfectly so thank you!